# Building R package: "Found 'rand', possibly from 'rand' (C)" NOTE when checking package

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, cran

I am building an R package that contains C++ code. Among others, I use the rand() function. The package checks and builds without any irregularities on my Linux machine. However, when I attempt to check the Windows build using the [Windows builder](http://win-builder.r-project.org/), I am getting the following warning:

```
* checking compiled code ... NOTE
File 'tagcloud/libs/i386/tagcloud.dll':
  Found 'rand', possibly from 'rand' (C)
    Object: 'overlap.o'
  Found 'srand', possibly from 'srand' (C)
    Object: 'overlap.o'
File 'tagcloud/libs/x64/tagcloud.dll':
  Found 'rand', possibly from 'rand' (C)
    Object: 'overlap.o'
  Found 'srand', possibly from 'srand' (C)
    Object: 'overlap.o'

Compiled code should not call entry points which might terminate R nor
write to stdout/stderr instead of to the console, nor the C RNG.
```

Here is some example code:

```
#include "Rcpp.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

RcppExport SEXP test(  ) {
  double x ;
  srand( (unsigned) time(NULL) );
  x = rand();
  return( 1 );
}
```

I don't understand the complaints about rand(). I also don't see where in the code I "call entry points which might terminate R" or "write to stdout/stderr", but then, if I remove the calls to rand/srand, this message disappears.

Google shows a lot of packages that seem to have the same NOTE in their check logs. Have you seen it? Is there a way I can get rid of it?

Comment: I think it is the last one that you should be worried about -- compiled code should not call the C RNG.

Comment: I'm confused. Why shouldn't I be using the C random number generator? What should I use instead?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your first question, but possibly has something to do with seed management, but [Rcpp has full access to R style p/d/r/q distributional functions via syntactic sugar](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-sugar.pdf).

Comment: Nice, but I do not need that; I am not doing any statistical calculation, I just need a bit of randomness for generating a visual tag cloud.

Comment: Well, you don't _have_ to use the random numbers generated that way for statistical calculations.

Comment: Anyways, the fact that I should not use rand() from a statistical point of view does not explain this warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The discussion in the comments already hits the essential point: R (as of late) complains about use of `rand()` and `srand()`.  [ Note that that is an R issue, not an Rcpp issue. ]

The reasoning is that at some points in the past, `rand()` was really bad on some systems. So warnings persist. See eg from [this page at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand):

> There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence produced. In the past, some implementations of rand() have had serious shortcomings in the randomness, distribution and period of the sequence produced (in one well-known example, the low-order bit simply alternated between 1 and 0 between calls).
>
> rand() is not recommended for serious random-number generation needs, like cryptography. It is recommended to use C++11's random number generation facilities to replace rand(). (since C++11)

In the case of an R, and Rcpp package, you *have no reason whatsoever* to rely on `rand()` as *R comes with several high-quality generators*.  Please see the Writing R Extension manual how to access them from C code, and the *numerous* Rcpp examples (here, Rcpp documtation, Rcpp Gallery) on how to access them from C++ via Rcpp.

Comment: I was given also another important reason on the R-devel list: the R set.seed() function does not influence the C seed(), and so by using the C RNG the user cannot reliably replicate the results. That said, of course there may be a reason to rely on the C RNG -- (i) it is standard C (ii) when I am building an interface to an existing C program or library I don't want to meddle too much in the internals of the program and (iii) it is notably faster, and for some purposes even poor randomization is more than sufficient.

Comment: That is the same thing. R's RNGs is independent and hence `set.seed()` does not go to `rand()` -- for that you would have `srand()`.  That is no different from using an RNG from, say, Boost.  Now, if you want a **faster RNG** you can simply **switch within R itself** or use a different RNG.  See my RcppZiggurat package which provides faster N(0,1) draws.

Comment: To be specific on Rcpp (http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/random-number-generation/), please use runif(), rnorm(), rt()...