# Building R package: Best way to remove NOTE due to 'rand' (C) and 'exit'

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, srand

I have created a Cpp package where C/Cpp functions like `std::cout`, `std::cerr`, `exit` and `srand` exists.
I have changed the `std::cout` with `Rcpp::Rcout` and `std::cerr` with `Rcpp::Rcerr`- thanks to Jelmer Ypma and this [help](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-rcout/).

What should be the best way to deal with `exit` and `srand`?

I have seen the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698164/building-r-package-found-rand-possibly-from-rand-c-note-when-checking). However, I was trying to tweak the original header files I wrote in the cpp package as minimum as possible and I need `srand` in subsequent functions also.
What is the optimal way of doing that (Keeping in mind that I may have to tweak the cpp files later and copy them to the R package.)

Comment: I've no idea how well it's supported by RCpp, but consider dumping `rand` and `srand` in favour of modern C++'s [<random> library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). Here's [a link to a presentation covering why you want to do this and how, at least for C++](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Comment: @SubrataPal  It is very clear in _Writing R Extension_: no `exit()`, no `abort()`, no `srand()`.  You will have to edit (or condition via `#if defined(...)`) it out.

Comment: @user4581301  a) We write it as Rcpp, lower-case c. b) R has perfectly good RNGs _and you want those in C++ code too_ for interop.  See Rcpp Gallery and many other places.

Comment: @user4581301, Thanks for your comment. I actually am not much familiar with these, but I think I used  `mt19937` using <random> library. However, the first link you gave, generates the same random numbers over different runs. I did not want that for my code. So I basically used time with the code: 
`std::srand((unsigned int) time(0));
std::random_device rd{};
std::mt19937 gen{rd()};
std::normal_distribution<> d{0,1};`

I forgot where I got this code, but it uses `srand`.

Comment: @user4581301, I'm sorry. I don't know why I started to give the time(0) at all. I just checked again and even without it, the random numbers are changing over the runs. (Possibly I initially ran it in an online compiler and the same random number came and I mixed things up.) Sorry for my previous wrong comment.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel given what my partner uses R for, good RNG doesn't surprise me.

Comment: @SubrataPal `std::random_device rd{}; std::mt19937 gen{rd()};` provides the services `std::srand((unsigned int) time(0));` does, more or less. More more, than less, mind you. You shouldn't need `srand` at all.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, thank you for your comment. 
I am looking at your Rcpp gallery [article](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/random-number-generation/)  and trying to follow that `R::rnorm(0,1)`. 

For `exit` in Cpp, I am using `Rcpp::stop`. 

I am closing this question after 1/2 days if anyone does not have anything more to suggest. 

Thanks again.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, somehow I mixed up these two. Possibly `srand` from old C classes, and initially tried it in online compiler and the same random number came again and again. I checked today on my local machine and there is no necessity to use that `std::srand((unsigned int) time(0))`. Sorry, I'm not exactly with a computer background and messed things up. 

Thanks again!